# C++ Create array on heap without initializing it

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, stack-memory

When you create an array like this (on the stack):

```
float array[5];
```

and then loop through the elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
}
```

it gives this

```
1.4013e-45 0 0 0 5.88052e-39
```

which shows that it hasn't been initialized.
However when I do this (on the heap):

```
float* array = new float[5];
```

it outputs

```
0 0 0 0 0
```

How can you create an array on the heap without initializing it?

Comment: Such allocation doesn't initialize array either. `0` is just as indeterminate value as `1.4013e-45` is.

Comment: With this: `float* array = new float[5];` nothing is initialized. However, with this: `float* array = new float[5]();` now yes they are initialized. Don't let some zeros confuse you :)

Comment: Pure luck it all 0s

Comment: I did it with 2147483647 values and got nothing but zeros. Is my memory just empty?

Comment: @NathanWood Who knows.. Maybe.. It's indeterminate.

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable is Undefined Behaviour. That's all there is to it. The program is simply invalid and you can't expect *anything*.

Comment: Oddly enough the GCC / Linux [implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8eac9c1cf3862ae) results in all zeros. That being said you should refrain from that practice.

Comment: Relevant reading: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @DimChtz, do you mean an additional `()` calls a for to assign zeros on all elements?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't initialize the values. Running this code shows that.

```
float* array = new float[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array[i] = 5;
    std::cout << array[i] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
delete[] array;
float* array2 = new float[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::cout << array2[i] << " ";
}
```

This then outputs

```
5 5 5 5 5 
0 0 5 5 5
```

or something similar.

Comment: Your use of `array2` invokes Undefined Behaviour. Your program is meaningless. The compiler is allowed to generate *whatever it likes*.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted a way to get undefined behavour. I thought that it was setting the values to zero, but this experiment shows it doesn't.

Comment: once you invoke UB, *all bets are off*. The compiler is allowed to do *anything* - including ignoring your code, doing what you intended, modifying *other* code to do different things (see [time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)), etc. The simple fact is, once you invoke UB, attempting to draw conclusions about what your program will do is pointless - it is simply *undefined* - no longer a valid C++ program.

Comment: I didn't phrase that well. I meant I didn't want to initialise the array to anything for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The result of

```
new float [5];
```

Does not modify the memory, but the heap memory may already have values, or be initialized by the implementation to have a particular value.